# Why Map is not a Map when comming from a Map with ? definition

Tags: angular, types

I have the following Angular code:

```
 var contactsKV: Map<string,string> = this.deviceContacts.contactList as Map<string,string>;
 var newContactsKV: Map<string,string> = new Map<string,string>;
 console.log("QQQ" + (contactsKV instanceof Map))
 console.log("ZZZ" + (newContactsKV instanceof Map))
```

Which throws:

```
QQQfalse
ZZZtrue
```

I would expect contactsKV to be of type Map. The only difference I can pinpoint in both variables is that contactList is defined optional:

```
export class Contact {  
  serialNumber?: string
  contactList?: Map<string,string>
}
```

And the atribute with the Contact is declared like this:

```
export class DeviceContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewMode = true;  
  @Input() deviceContacts: Contact= {};//Neither works if I remove '= {}'
```

Any ideas on why Angular would do this? I need to use Map functions like delete() but they are not recognized in contactsKV as the type seems to be something else.

Comment: How do you instantiate `contactList`?

Comment: `contactList` is not a map. Have you checked if its not undefined ?

Comment: @Wandrille  I added how the Contact is declared in the class

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I added how the Contact is declared in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both empty object (`{}`) and `Map` are dictionnaries, `{}` is not a `Map`.

If you want an empty map create a new one : `new Map<string,string>;`.

Edit: Seems like you were passing an object in input that was not a map !

Comment: But I am passing it as @Input, if I create a new one, the Map that is passed as Input is overwritten with an empty Map

Comment: I left the declaration as   @Input() deviceContacts: Contact; but the type is still not Map

Comment: Then you're not passing a Map to your input. Try to a `console.log` in `ngOnInit` to see which value you're getting.

Comment: You are a genius. Can you put in the answer that I was passing data without really initializing it?